# Why do Go and Python return different result when dividing big numbers?

Tags: python, go, numbers, division

```
// In golang    
x, y := big.NewFloat(26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960), big.NewFloat(14484.162361)  
z := new(big.Float).Quo(x, y)
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%f", z))
```

> output:
>   1861311315012765262390495455137379355146730679910059382988079104.000000

```
// In python
v1 = 26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960000000
v2= 14484162361
print v1/v2
```

> output:1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170

Comment: I think you are missing a decimal point in your v2 variable?

Comment: @Alan, Thanks for your quick answer. Exactly the result of python is what I want. I don't know why golang return different result and I think it's wrong.

Comment: He just explained it to you. You divide by 14484.162361 in go and by 14484162361 in python

Comment: @T.Nel That wouldn't be the problem, as both the dividend and divisor are multiplied by the same number (1e6), so the quotient should be the same.

Answer (score 6):

You are not doing the same operation in Go and in Python. In Go you divide 2 floating point numbers, while in Python you divide 2 integer numbers. The results are only "roughly" equal because the input numbers you provide  lose precision, and the accuracy of the floating point operation is also limited (insufficient).

If you perform the same integer division in Go (using the [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) type), you get the same result:

```
i, ok := big.NewInt(0).SetString("26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960000000", 10)
if !ok {
    panic("invalid")
}
j, ok := big.NewInt(0).SetString("14484162361", 10)
if !ok {
    panic("invalid")
}

k := big.NewInt(0).Quo(i, j)
fmt.Println(k)
```

This outputs:

```
1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170
```

If you want to perform floating point division in Go, don't use `float64` type to represent your inputs, as they are limited in precision. This will happen because you created your input numbers using [`big.NewFloat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewFloat) which has a parameter of `float64` type, so the constants you pass will be implicitly converted to `float64` and you already lose precision.

Instead use the [`big.Float`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float) type, and specify your input as `string` values and set it using [`Float.SetString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.SetString); and manually increase the precision (using [`Float.SetPrec()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.SetPrec)). If you do so, you will get the "same" result (same in the integer part, plus some fraction value):

```
x, ok := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(500).SetString("26959535291011309493156476344723991336010898738574164086137773096960")
if !ok {
    panic("invalid")
}
y, ok := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(500).SetString("14484.162361")
if !ok {
    panic("invalid")
}
z := new(big.Float).SetPrec(500).Quo(x, y)
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%f", z))
```

Output:

```
1861311315012765306929610463010191006516769515973403833769533170.518151
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WYtJfndJlZR).

Note that precision of [`Float.Quo()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Quo) depends on:

> Precision, rounding, and accuracy reporting are as for Add.

Which is:

> If z's precision is 0, it is changed to the larger of x's or y's precision before the operation. Rounding is performed according to z's precision and rounding mode; and z's accuracy reports the result error relative to the exact (not rounded) result.

Comment: Yes, you got my point. So that looks I used wrong methods to do the calculation. Thank you @icza.